# Как работает placeholder на поле number?

Tags: html, css

У меня есть поле ввода имени и возраста. В поле имя прописано `plaseholder = "Имя"`, тоже самое я прописал и в поле возраст, но слово **"возраст"** он у меня не выводит. Как это реализовать?

Comment: Возможно, всё дело в опечатке - placeholder.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, т.к. он вызван опечаткой.

Comment: @meine закрыть его не могу,т.к на него даны ответы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот пример. Всё работает....

```html
<input type="number" placeholder="Возраст" id="age" name="age" min="10" max="100">
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: <input name="age" type="number" class = "num" size="15" maxleght="5" plaseholder = "Возраст"><br>
Либо я перегрелся,либо что то не так. Где у меня ошибка тут?

Comment: @user328894 У вас `plaseholder`, а должно быть `placeholder`

Comment: Господи. Спасибо огромное,весь код уже перебрал,а ошибка на лице) Еще раз спасибо

Comment: @user328894, тогда прими ответ нажатием на галочку слева от него.